# How to write Windows-compatible command lines in Terraform local-exec provisioner

Tags: curl, cmd, command-line, terraform

I am trying to run a command (a `curl` invocation) using terraform's `local-exec` provisioner under windows. It runs using `cmd /C` according to the logs.

Same command pasted in the terminal works fine.

```
resource "null_resource" "search_indexes" {
  for_each = local.indexes_set
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  <<EOT
curl  https://${var.cognitive_search_name}.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview  --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'api-key: ${var.key}' --data '@${each.key}'
     EOT
  }
}
```

The output is as follows (abriged from progress reports):

```
module.(...).search_indexes["test-index.json"] (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "curl ...

exit status 6.  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application // actually part of first header argument
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1...F' // actually part of second header argument, api-key
```

so I see that it is run with `cmd /C` and words after the space in --header parameters are considered new URLs.

Using double quotes around parameters such as `--headers`, some escaping, but it still gives the same error.

Copy-pasted command placed in windows terminal works fine.

I suspect `cmd` or terraform do something to alter the command line so it is not looking correctly. How can I achieve correct behavior?

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help explaining how the argument(s) after option `/C` are interpreted by the Windows command processor depending on multiple criteria. There can be used free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with an __added include__ filter __Process Name is cmd.exe__ to log all registry, file and network accesses of `cmd.exe` being executed to run `curl.exe`. Double click on any `cmd.exe` line in log and select tab __Process__.

Comment: There is displayed the command line used to start `cmd.exe`. Now it can be seen with which arguments `cmd.exe` was started and see in the log how `cmd.exe` tries its best to execute the command line not being in correct syntax for a successful execution of `curl.exe` found obviously by `cmd.exe` although not specified with its fully qualified file name. I suppose that the url should be enclosed also in `"` as it contains `=` which is interpreted by `cmd.exe` as an argument separator like space, horizontal tab, comma, semicolon or OEM encoded no-break space.

Comment: All `'` having no special meaning for `cmd.exe` in comparison to Linux/Mac shell interpreters must be replaced by `"` in the arguments list to get all characters between the two double quotes interpreted as literal characters with the exception of `%` with by default disabled delayed expansion. The reason for the failed execution is most likely in one of the variable parts of the command line which is not posted in the question making it nearly impossible to really answer the question. So I posted just some general suggestions as a problem on unknown command line cannot be solved by us.

Comment: There should be added in __Process Monitor__ also the include filter __Process Name is curl.exe__ to be able to look also on the command line of `curl.exe` started by `cmd.exe`. The difference between the command line for starting `cmd.exe` and the command line for starting `curl.exe` draws conclusion from how `cmd.exe` interpreted the arguments before starting `curl.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure and conventions for quoting and escaping on the command line are quite different between Unix and Windows.

On Unix, quoting and escaping is a concern of the shell itself, and Unix shells typically understand the contents of single quotes `'` as totally verbatim text, while the contents of `"` can contain some interpolation metacharacters but spaces are still taken literally, rather than separators. The shell handles the tokenization into a set of arguments and passes those arguments to the program as an array of strings.

On Windows, quoting and escaping is the concern of the program being run<sup>1</sup>, and *not* of the command interpreter `cmd.exe`. The command line you type will (more or less) be passed exactly as you wrote it to the program you're running -- `curl` in this case -- and [it's left entirely up to that program to decide](https://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINNOSTANDARD) what symbols like `"` and `'` might mean and where to draw the boundaries between separate arguments.

In practice, most modern CLI applications on Windows are either built using Microsoft Visual C++ or with some other software that emulates its command line parsing conventions. If `curl` is such a program (which is likely, since it is written in C) then unfortunately [the relevant rules are quite complicated](https://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULES), but for your purposes here we can reduce it to a few key facts:

- The single quote character `'` is taken literally. Unlike on Unix, it does not represent verbatim text.
- You can use the double quote character `"` to represent a sequence where spaces should be taken literally rather than used as argument separators.

Therefore in order to write a command line that is portable across both Unix and Windows, you will need to use the double quote character `"` and ensure that the strings you interpolate within the quotes don't contain any characters that would be interpreted as special by either set of parsing rules.

In your case, I think that would be the following as long as you can be sure that none of the variables this refers to will contain quote characters, `$` characters, or anything else that a Unix shell might interpret as special inside double quotes:

```
    command =  <<-EOT
      curl "https://${var.cognitive_search_name}.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "api-key: ${var.key}" --data "@${each.key}"
    EOT
```

Writing portable command lines is quite challenging due to this significant architectural difference between Unix and Windows, which is one of the reasons why [the Terraform documentation recommends considering provisioners as a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort). If possible it would typically be better to use a specialized provider to make a request like this, but I'm not familiar enough with the API you're requesting here to know which provider would potentially offer it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the command interpreter *does* do some parsing of its own to handle environment variable substitution like `%%FOO%%` and the I/O redirection sequences like pipes and `>`/`<` markers.

The command interpreter therefore has [its own separate escaping syntax](https://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCMDRULES) which can potentially come into play if your command line ended up including any of the *command interpreter's* special characters.

Fortunately the command interpreter's parser *also* has some basic understanding of `"` as a marker for turning off *some of* its special processing, but we still need to watch out for `%%VARIABLE%%` sequences inside quotes, so you'll need to be sure that your variables to substitute don't contain anything like that.